# how to revoke update grant on one table in one schema(crm) and user(cus)

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, privileges, sql-grant

i have lots of table in one schema with given grant(select,update,insert,delete) And now i want to remove the update grant on the attendence table how can i do 
schema(crm)
user(cus)
table(attendence)
DB (dev)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect as user who owns the ATTENDANCE table

```
connect owner_username/its_password@database_name
```

and then

```
revoke update on attendance from some_user;
```

---

**[EDIT, after reading your comment]**

If there are many users in the database, consider creating **roles**. For example, roles RS1 and RS2. Then

```
grant update, delete, select, insert on a1 to rs1;
grant select, insert on a1 to rs2;
```

Then you'd grant those roles to appropriate users. The ones that can do *everything* would be granted RS1 role, while the others would be granted RS2, such as

```
grant rs1 to s1;
grant rs2 to s2;
grant rs2 to s3;
grant rs1 to s1;
```

Otherwise (i.e. if you don't want to use roles), you'd grant all those privileges directly to each user.

Comment: i have 
schema:crm 
user:admin 
Tables(A1,A2,A3,A4,...A100) 
and  
OS: S1 ,S2,S3,..,S10
i want that 
admin( S1) can (update, delete, select, insert) but admin(S2) can only (select ,insert ) but not (update ,delete) the table and its data.
(i am trying using trigger,grant etc but stuck) how i can do this ....?
kindly share the solution.

Comment: i want to give  grant or revoke on the OS_name basics  not user basics

Comment: How are operating system users related to database users? Are you saying that many OS users share the same database account? Well, I wouldn't do that (if I were you), but create one database user for every person.

Comment: mean many person shares one  database user. i want that only selected person can only update or insert the data in the table

Comment: As I said: in my opinion, every person should have their own database user, if you want to do what you're saying.